# z3 C++ API & ite

Tags: z3

Maybe I missed something, but what is the way of constructing an if-then-else expression using the z3 C++ API ?

I could use the C API for that, but I'm wondering why there is no such function in the C++ API.

regards,
Julien

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can mix the C and C++ APIs. The file `examples/c++/example.cpp` contains an example using the C API to create the if-then-else expression. The function `to_expr` is essentially wrapping a `Z3_ast` with the C++ "smart pointer" `expr` that automatically manages the reference counters for us.

```cpp
void ite_example() {
    std::cout << "if-then-else example\n";
    context c;

    expr f    = c.bool_val(false);
    expr one  = c.int_val(1);
    expr zero = c.int_val(0);
    expr ite  = to_expr(c, Z3_mk_ite(c, f, one, zero));

    std::cout << "term: " << ite << "\n";
}
```

[I just added the `ite` function to the C++ API](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/c430fe26aa30). It will be available in the next release (v4.3.2). If you want you can add to the `z3++.h` file in your system. A good place to include is after the function `implies`:

```cpp
/**
   \brief Create the if-then-else expression <tt>ite(c, t, e)</tt>

   \pre c.is_bool()
*/
friend expr ite(expr const & c, expr const & t, expr const & e) {
    check_context(c, t); check_context(c, e);
    assert(c.is_bool());
    Z3_ast r = Z3_mk_ite(c.ctx(), c, t, e);
    c.check_error();
    return expr(c.ctx(), r);
}
```

Using this function, we can write:

```cpp
void ite_example2() {
    std::cout << "if-then-else example2\n";
    context c;
    expr b = c.bool_const("b");
    expr x = c.int_const("x");
    expr y = c.int_const("y");
    std::cout << (ite(b, x, y) > 0) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566727/implement-z3-maximize-in-c