# Bit-vector value in decimal

Tags: z3

Using C++ APIs, how can you extract the decimal value of a bit-vector constant from a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several C-Functions that allow you to extract different types of values, depending on the expected size of the numerals: `Z3_get_numeral_int`, `Z3_get_numeral_uint`, `Z3_get_numeral_uint64`, `Z3_get_numeral_int64`. For numbers that don't fit into those basic types, we can use the `Z3_get_numeral_string` function to get a string representation that can be parsed into your preferred big-int representation.

Note that these functions are C-functions, not C++ functions, but those two APIs mix nicely. (See e.g, also [z3 C++ API & ite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160468/z3-c-api-ite)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Writing something like `int val; Z3_get_numeral_int(bv.ctx(), bv, &val);` did the job.